# Can't read file stored in res/raw

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm unable to successfully get the contents of a public key file that I have stored in my res/raw directory.

My objective is to read the contents of this file into a `File` object that I will then pass along to another function that requires a `File` object as one of its parameters.

It's important to note that this file contains an X509 key, which I believe means that I need to read its contents as bytes (not text).

This is in the onCreate method of my main activity:

```
String filename = context.getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.public_key);
Log.d(TAG, filename);
File publicKeyFile = new File(filename);
if (!publicKeyFile.exists()) Log.d(TAG, "no public key file");
```

Which yields this output:

> raw/public_key
> no public key file

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My objective is to read the contents of this file into a File object that I will then pass along to another function that requires a File object as one of its parameters.

That is not possible, unless you make your own local copy of that file.

> What am I doing wrong?

Raw resources are not files. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK file. If you want a `File`, open an `InputStream` on the raw resource, copy its contents out to a local file, then use the local file.

Comment: OK. I'm clearly going down the wrong path. I can put this public key file anywhere that I want. The reason that I put it in the resources folder was for this specific purpose - to read it into a File object. What folder should I store it so that I can read it that way? I'm hoping to not have to reference the entire file path, but rather just reference 'public_key' (not '~/dir/dir/dir/.../public_key'). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Randall: "What folder should I store it so that I can read it that way?" -- there is nothing that you can ship with your APK that is addressible directly as a `File` object. If you want to ship it, whether you use a raw resource or assets, all you can get is an `InputStream`. If you are using some third-party closed-source code that only supports a `File`, you have to make a local copy of the data, or switch to some other code that supports an `InputStream`.

Comment: All right. Thanks for that advice. I just wasted two days of my life. Back to the drawing board. Thank you!